# how to get color scheme in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

is it possible in Liferay to get programmatically color scheme of theme?

I have to include different icons depending of current color scheme. I know that it is possible to do it by using css but in my issue it is better to get color scheme in java code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the color scheme of the current page that you are in try the following code

```
ColorScheme colorScheme = (ColorScheme )request.getAttribute(WebKeys.WebKeys.COLOR_SCHEME);
```

Comment: WebKeys.COLOR_SCHEME is not accessable from portlets. Use the String "COLOR_SCHEME":   ColorScheme colorScheme = (ColorScheme )request.getAttribute("COLOR_SCHEME");

Comment: yeah my bad, I digged ServicePreAction for code and thought WebKeys is the kernal one. +1